# No puedo enviar variable POST con jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

necesito de vuestra ayuda. Mi problema es el siguiente:

- Necesito enviar un ID a través de una variable POST sin tener que hacerlo en un formulario.

He intentando con AJAX JQUERY pero no me funciona al momento de intentar rescatar la variable $_POST en mi archivo PHP no me la obtiene. Tengo el siguiente código pero no me esta funcionando, les dejo el código de mis archivos:

**INDEX PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Probando Jquery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
      <h1>ENVIAR VARIABLE POST JQUERY AJAX</h1>
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control d-none" id="inputName" value="1">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEditar">editar</button>
  </main>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="controller.js"></script>
  <!-- LLAMO A MI ARCHIVO PHP PARA MOSTRAR LA VARIABLE POST-->
  <?php require_once "controller.php"?>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnEditar").click(function(){

        var dato = $("#inputName").val();
        alert(dato);


        $.ajax({
                url: 'controller.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id_dato:dato},
                success: function(){
                   alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
                }
        });

    });
});
```

**CONTROLLER.PHP**

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST["id_dato"])){
        echo $_POST["id_dato"];
    }
?>
```

- En el archivo INDEX.PHP estoy ocupando un input oculto que tiene un value=1 ese value es el que necesito enviar como variable POST a mi archivo PHP.

espero haberme explicado bien, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

1.- revisa tu consola en el apartado de Red/xhr/encabezados y revisa si se esta enviando la variable id_dato=1.

2.- cambia

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Probando Jquery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>ENVIAR VARIABLE POST JQUERY AJAX</h1>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control d-none" id="inputName" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEditar">editar</button>
        </main>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="controller.js"></script>
        <!-- LLAMO A MI ARCHIVO PHP PARA MOSTRAR LA VARIABLE POST-->
        <?php require_once "controller.php"?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Por:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Probando Jquery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>ENVIAR VARIABLE POST JQUERY AJAX</h1>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control d-none" id="inputName" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEditar">editar</button>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: se me olvido mencionar pero igual probé con !empty(). Creo que si me esta mandando la variable porqe hice un console.log(data) y en consola me muestra el valor de la variable. La verdad no se que puede ser...

Comment: A  ver pon así tu URL

     **url: '/controller.php',**

Comment: no. de hecho ni siquiera me ejecuta el  function en success..

Comment: cambia de posición tus URL de js al <head> bro. y no necesitas poner el <?php require_once "controller.php"?>

Comment: Investiga en google por favor como utilizar el inspeccionador de elementos para ver en consola los errores que te tire el código.

Answer (score 0):

cambia

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnEditar").click(function(){
        var dato = $("#inputName").val();
        alert(dato);
        $.ajax({
                url: 'controller.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id_dato:dato},
                success: function(){
                   alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
                }
        });

    });
});
```

por

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnEditar").click(function(){
        let url = "controller.php";
        var dato = $("#inputName").val();
        $.post(url, {'id_dato':dato}, function(data){
                alert( 'data')
            }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: claro, el alert(data) me esta mostrando un valor 1, es decir, el value del input. Pero en el archivo controller.php no me encuentra la variable POST["id_dato"]. La verdad ya nose que es lo que puede ser, saludos.

Comment: imprime la variable $_POST sin mas a ver que datos hay